# Separate specific values from a cell value in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel sheet with values shown as below:

[image: sheet1]

I'm trying to separate the numeric values given in the first column to columns **a,b** and **c** so that the final output should look like

[image: ss]

Now, I can get the value in the a column using the formula

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("x",A1)-1)
```

But I'm struggling to get the other values (column **b** and **c**)

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another formula option

Assume data housed in `A2:A5`

To find "a", in `B2` formula copied down :

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("x",A2)-1)
```

To find "b", in `C2` formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID($A2,FIND("(",$A2)+1,ROW($1:$9)))
```

To find "c", in `D2` formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID($A2,FIND("x",$A2,FIND("(",A2))+1,ROW($1:$9)))
```

Comment: very nice and concise approach :) the use of `0+` is the same as `--` or `NUMBERVALUE` function.

Comment: what does 9^9 mean in the formula's?

Comment: 9^9 in the Lookup formula is a short form of Bignum 9.99999999999999E+307 ( a largest number in Excel), try to Google in "Bignum" for further detailing.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably cook up something to do this using Excel's built-in functionalities, but it'd be long, difficult to grasp and prone to errors if the input format ever changes. Instead, I would probably use VBA to create a simple custom formula that can extract the numbers using a regular expression.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>  to open the Developer Tools
2. Go to `Tools > References` and check `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5`
3. Choose `Insert > Module`

Enter the following code:

```
Function FINDNUMBERS(sInput As String, Optional iIndex As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String

    strPattern = "[0-9]+"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(sInput)

    FINDNUMBERS = Matches(iIndex)
End Function
```

You can then call the function in your worksheet like this:

```
=FINDNUMBERS(A1;0)
```

Where the first parameter is the cell you'd like to get the numbers from, and the second parameter is the position of the number you would like. Enter 0 for the first number found, 1 for the second number, etc.

Comment: is it possible without using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

To find `b`, try

```
=--MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,FIND("x",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"x(","[["))-FIND("(",A2)-1)
```

> The logic is to use **FIND** function to find the position of the second `x` by replacing/substituting the first `x` with another symbol which is `[` in my example, then you will know the ending point of value `b`.
>
> Use the **FIND** function again to find the position of `(` then you will know the starting point of value `b`, the difference between the two will be the length of value `b`,
>
> then you can use **MID** function to return value `b` from the string. The starting point of the **MID** function is determined by the position of `(`.
>
> Double minus signs `--` in front of the formula is used to turn the value into a numeric value. It is working in the same way as **NUMBERVALUE** function. *This is optional if you do not need to show the result as number.*

To find `c`, try

```
=--MID(A2,FIND("x",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"x(","[["))+1,FIND(" ",A2)-FIND("x",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"x(","[[")))
```

> The logic is similar to the previous one. Use **FIND** function to find the position of the space `" "` and find the position of the second `x`, the difference of the two positions is the length of value `c`,
>
> then use **MID** function to return value `c` from the string. The starting point of the **MID** function is determined by the position of the second `x`.

Replace `A2` to suit your case.

[image: Demo]

Comment: can you explain/break down your formula's for better understanding? :) Also will the formula's work in excel 2007?

Comment: @Bumba all functions used are available in Excel 2007. Next time please mention your version of excel in the question. I have edited my answer to include some explanations hope that helps. Try the formula out and play with each function with other scenarios and let me know if you have any question.